# Button for Moving to Next Picture in Gallery-Picture-Sequence?

Tags: mysql, pagination

I have 2 buttons "next" and "Previous" and I want to move through my pictures. Pictures names are stored in a mysql database and I use the following Mysql code to get the current picture.

```
"SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE picid = '12'"
```

all of the pictures can be accessed using the following Mysql code ($tag is just a variable with a string)

```
"SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE tag = '$tag'"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What is it you are actually asking about?? You show two SQL statements, though your post title is asking about a 'Next Picture button'. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: Edga, No... I had no idea what to do

Comment: PenguinCoder, I want to make a page that shows a picture that has 2 buttons "next" and "Previous" when they click next it goes to the next picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you sort these images? You can always select the next one based on their order:

Next image (12 is order value of the current one)

```
'SELECT id FROM pictures WHERE order > 12 LIMIT 1'
```

Comment: They have the option of ordering it by "ORDER BY rating DESC" or "ORDER BY views DESC"

Comment: what should I put in place of the order?

Comment: You should at least know what you're doing. "order" is any column you're using to order the photos. For example rating or views, as you said in your previous comment.

Comment: Considering what you just said, if my query to get all of the resutls is "SELECT * FROM  `picutres` WHERE  `active` =1 ORDER BY  `likes` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30" And the query for showing the current picture is "SELECT * FROM  `pictures` WHERE  `id` = 1045 LIMIT 1" Then the query to get the next picture in the correct order is "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE `active` = 1 AND likes > 1045 LIMIT 1" which doesn't work because it is looking for any record that has more than 1045 likes!

Comment: How many likes does the record with ID 1045 have? Suppose that 23. Then the query to select the next one would be `SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE active = 1 AND likes <= 23 AND id <> 1045 ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: great but what if they are five records that have 23 likes then isn't it going to loop several records?

Comment: Order by a second identifier that is unique - `ORDER BY likes DESC, id DESC`.